# Cannot access the Couchbase 4.1.0 Web Console

Tags: couchbase

I'm new to Couchbase and I ran into a problem which I couldn't solve by browsing the web looking for help. I've recently installed Couchbase 4.1.0 Community Edition onto a Windows Server 2012 machine. Everything worked well, I've set up admin password, but I can't login onto the Web Console. I've tried both "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" with identical results. This is what I see when I open the Web Console:

[Couchbase Web Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syj8r.png)

When I enter correct user name and password and hit "Sign In", the page just reloads and shows blank fields. Nothing else happens. When I enter an incorrect password, I see the following:

[Couchbase Web Console - incorrect password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anizX.png)

That's it. No action at all. I've tried resetting the password many times (cbreset_password.exe), even reinstalling the whole thing, but nothing changed.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thx.

Comment: When you say "localhost" and "127.0.0.1", I assume you are trying them on port 8091? Are there any errors in the JavaScript console that you could post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now know the answer and it has nothing to do with Couchbase itself. After weeks of inactivity on this task, I wanted to download the Oracle SQL Developer. As with all Oracle software, I had to pass a single sign-on form.

I filled in my username and password, and bang, the form merely reset itself! No error message, nothing. I've immediately had a deja vu. So I started to suspect something has to be wrong with the Internet Explorer's cookie settings. (It's all on a virtual machine which I only use occasionally, otherwise I'd have noticed it way sooner.)

I downloaded and installed Firefox, and both Couchbase and Oracle sign-on started to work! :)